# How to get the element type of slice?

Tags: go, reflection, slice, go-reflect

If there is a struct like:

```golang
type A struct {
  Arr []int
}
```

How can I get the element type in the slice `arr`?

for example, an empty A instance is passed in, how can I get the `int` type?

```golang
func PrintElementType(obj interface{}) {
    objType := reflect.TypeOf(obj)
    for i := 0; i < objType.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldType := objType.Field(i).Type
        // here I got 'slice'
        fmt.Println(fieldType.Kind())
        // here I got '[]int', I think 'int' type is stored somewhere...
        fmt.Println(fieldType)
        // so, is there any way to get 'int' type?
        fmt.Println("inner element type?")
    }
}

func main() {
    a := A{}
    PrintElementType(a)
}
```

Comment: `fmt.Println(fieldType.Elem())`

Comment: @icza: would you mind re-posting your comment as an answer so it could be upvoted and accepted? This could lead to a better experience for folks googling and finding this question in the future

Answer (score 2):

If you have the [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) type descriptor of a slice type, use its `Type.Elem()` method to get the type descriptor of the slice's element type:

```
fmt.Println(fieldType.Elem())
```

`Type.Elem()` may also be used to get the element type if the  type's Kind is `Array`, `Chan`, `Map`, `Ptr`, or `Slice`, but it panics otherwise. So you should check the kind before calling it:

```
if fieldType.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
    fmt.Println("Slice's element type:", fieldType.Elem())
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_ALJm1mdLEU)):

```
slice
[]int
Slice's element type: int
```